# Upgrading from 10.10 on my laptop

Tags: 10.10

I'm currently using 10.10 and it is not supported any more. When I do the upgrade, after install the screen on my laptop is just black and I see nothing. I've tried to upgrade several times and each time I have to uninstall and reinstall 10.10 and decline the upgrade. I would like to upgrade but until this issue is resolved I can't. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in that you should not really be offered the online upgrade as I believe that you can only upgrade in this way from the previous version (11.10) or the previous LTS version (10.04).

You will have to do  fresh installation of 12.04 but if you have a separate partition for /home your data and configuration will be retained. I assume from your recent multiple reinstallations that that is the case and that you are familiar with the partitioning bit (ie making sure you don't wipe out the /home data!) but if not come back.

You will need to bear in mind also that since 10.10 (3 versions ago) the ubuntu desktop environment has dramatically changed and there must be a risk that you can experience issues due to configuration conflicts. I therefore strongly recommend that you backup all your data before you begin as you cannot rule out the possibility of having to start from scratch and restoring your data from the backup medium.

Hope this helps

Ian